# Easy way to do a network install of OS?

Tags: installation, linux-mint

I've always seen the option of doing a network install when I'm going through the OS installation process. Awhile back I started looking into how to do it but I don't know the questions to ask.

Specifically I'm looking to install Linux Mint 18 x86 on a laptop and I have a desktop running Windows 10 x64. I'll be installing from my home network.

What software, network settings, configurations, files, etc. do I need to do a fresh install over a network?

Comment: You could potentially make an image and push that image to multiple networked PCs using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). . . worked well when I used it for that purpose a while back. I'm not sure if you need to keep Windows and install Linux on a separate partition or if you're wiping Windows and will only have Linux or what but you could also use  [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) installed onto Windows to then boot Linux within Windows. The settings, configs, etc. will vary and you'd need to just get it setup, test, and so forth.

Comment: Your question is kind of broad.  You're asking for a tutorial, or general knowledge on a process, which would be answered either by a link to a resource somewhere else or an answer that would be very long.  A more in-scope question would deal with a specific issue that wasn't clear from your initial research.  [From review queue.](http://superuser.com/review/close/559815)

Answer (score 1):

You typically need to set up a BOOTP + DHCP server then boot over the network via PXE. Here's a guide on how to do so:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=96322

Getting this setup is definitely going to take some time and effort, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can save lot of time doing it with [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html#linux)

You can also see here an old how to

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=126082

(I'm related to Serva development)